# How to solve this functional equation involving hyperbolic functions?

Tags: mathematical-physics, functional-equations, hyperbolic-functions

I'm reading [this](https://www.elsevier.com/books/statistical-mechanics/pathria/978-0-12-382188-1) (physics) book. They have the recurrence relation (book eq. 14.2.14)

$$f(K_1,0)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\{2\sqrt{\cosh(2K_1)}\}+\frac{1}{2}f(\ln\sqrt{\cosh(2K_1)},0).\qquad(1)$$

They give the following solution (book eq. 14.2.15)

$$f(K_1,0)=-\ln(2\cosh K_1).\qquad(2)$$

I tried to check the solution was correct simply plugging (2) into (1) but end up with a $\ln(\cosh(\ln(\cosh(K_1)))$ thing.

**Questions:**

1. How do I obtain the solution (2) from (1)?
2. Is there an easy way to check the solution is correct?

Comment: $\cosh(\ln(x)) = \dfrac{x^{2}+1}{2x}$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{align}
\cosh x = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
\end{align}
then you see that
\begin{align}
2 \cosh( \ln( \sqrt{\cosh(2K_1)}) =&\ 2\frac{\exp\left(\ln \sqrt{\cosh(2K_1)}\right)+\exp\left(-\ln \sqrt{\cosh(2K_1)} \right)}{2}\\
=&\ 2\frac{\sqrt{\cosh 2K_1}+ (\sqrt{\cosh 2K_1})^{-1}}{2} =  \frac{\cosh 2K_1 +1}{\sqrt{\cosh 2K_1}}.
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(2\sqrt{\cosh 2K_1} \right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\cosh 2K_1 +1}{\sqrt{\cosh 2K_1}} \right)=&\ -\frac{1}{2}\ln\left( 2\cosh(2K_1)+2\right)\\
=&\ -\frac{1}{2}\ln(4\cosh^2 K_1).
\end{align}

Comment: Nice check, thank you. Any idea on how to derive the solution from equation (1)?